# DataTable editMode primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to use the p:datatable of primefaces with cellEdit mode https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml.

When i use this code

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();  

 String id =   event.getComponent().getClientId();
}
```

The 'id' that i get is form 'event.getComponent().getClientId();' is for datatable and not for the cell that i have just modified?

How i can get the client id of the edit cell?

Thanks

Comment: Cell's id render dynamically, so you get for what ?

Comment: I want ti get the id of the cell that i edited

Comment: You can get it, but i can imagine you get for what, my suggestion is  use javascript. When you edit a row, you can get row'id, then you set input value = row'id, then you submit to server via trigger a button.